# How to call a controller from view in codeigniter 4

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I have this function in controller in codeigniter 4. How to call this function in view?

```
public function permission($module_id)
    {
        echo 111;exit;
        $permission_model = new PermissionModel();
        $role = session()->get('roleId');
        $data = array($permission_model->where('id',$module_id)->first());
      
    }
```

In codeigniter 3 it works like this
$this->Auth->permission(1); But how can I call this function in view ,using codeigniter 4?

Comment: [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72961540/edit) showing us the Controller source code where you return the view.

Comment: [Adding Dynamic Data to the View](https://codeigniter4.github.io/CodeIgniter4/outgoing/views.html#adding-dynamic-data-to-the-view)